# Is there a good synonym for "recency"?

Tags: synonyms

I wasn't sure I had ever used/heard the word *recency* before but, when trying to come up for a word to describe *proximity in time*, it popped into my head. It's in the [Merriam-Webster dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recency) so I must have come across it somewhere before. They do not list a synonym. Is anyone aware of one?

Comment: [Yesterday?](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/yesterday)

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions! I have +1'd several that I found helpful - In the end, I think I just have to become comfortable with its use in the future. I find that @Kris suggestion of "temporal proximity" might also be an appropriate alternative for my specific context. Cheers

Comment: .....huh. I could have sworn there was a word like this (other than "recency" itself), but I can't think of any.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as *recency* is concerned,  *recentness* appears to be the only synonym available.

However, from what I understand from your question, ***temporal proximity*** is what fits your need best.

Comment: Um, assuming that those needs don't include "not sounding like Spock."

Answer (score 5):

There are some synonyms, but the choice of which one to use depends on context.

- **Novelty**
- **Freshness**
- **Youth**

If you want to describe *the state of having just happened*, **recency** is your best bet, barring other forms of the same word (*recentness* and, even more rarely, *recentity*).

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few not mentioned yet:

- newness, modernness
- presence (which implies spatial proximity, too)
- contemporaneity

Answer (score 1):

There are a whole lot of synonyms for *recent*, so it is not hard to make a noun out of one of them. The following may fit:

- currentness
- contemporariness

Answer (score 0):

https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/contemporaneousness

See also on this page 'synchrony'.